# ksh : pattern should not match but it does

Tags: glob, ksh

I'm unable to understand why the following pattern matches here:

```
$ [[ "abcdef12" == ab!(cd)* ]] && echo matched
matched
```

According to the man page (unless I've misunderstood something) it should not :

```
!(pattern-list)
Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

How "cd" could be matched by "!(cd)" ?

(ksh version used : "AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01")

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use the [...] form, instead of the [[...]] form ?

Comment: since '[' ']' is only for upward compalibility purposes I'm pretty sure that it doesn't even support patterns

BTW I've found a working method:

Comment: (continued)
The following pattern matches any string starting with "ab" followed by anything except "xx" : 
ab@(!(xx)&@(??))* 
Not supported by orignal ksh93 apparently but works on relatively old versions, so I'm ok with that.

Comment: the [ ... ] form  works for me, but is more verbose, needing `if ...then ...else...fi` , I prefer the brevity of the [[..]] form. (Version A 2020.0.0)

Comment: @mao
It's very strange that the "[ "<string>" == <pattern> ]" matches since between single squares brackets pattern matching is not supported.
For instance:

[[ a = a* ]] && print match => outputs "match"
[ a = a* ] && print match => outputs nothing

Answer (score 0):

Understood !

since "!(cd)" matches also empty string, the pattern matches "abcdef12"

I'm now looking for the best way to match any string beginning with "ab" *not followed* by "cd" using only shell pattern (not regexps, it have to work with old ksh versions)